# How do I configure Spring to partially and optionally override properties?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-java-config

I would like to have a properties setup which can, on certain environments, override specific properties. For example, our default JDBC properties for dev are:

- db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ourdb
- db.username=root
- db.password=

The problem is that some of our devs would like to have a different username/password on the db, or possibly even a non locally hosted db. The same is true for our rabbitMQ configuration, which currently uses a similar localhost, guest/guest setup. Being able to override the properties of certain elements of this configuration on a per-developer basis would allow us to move much of the infrastructure/installation requirements for building the software off the local machine and onto dedicated servers.

I have set-up a simple project to wrap my head around the configuration required to achieve what I want, and this is my first foray into the world of spring property configuration, since up till now, property loading and management is done with some custom code. Here is my setup:

```
class Main_PropertyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String environment = System.getenv("APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT"); // Environment, for example: "dev"
        String subEnvironment = System.getenv("APPLICATION_SUB_ENVIRONMENT"); // Developer name, for example: "joe.bloggs"
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", environment);
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.sub", subEnvironment);

        try(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertyTestConfiguration.class)) {
            Main_PropertyTest main = context.getBean(Main_PropertyTest.class);
            main.printProperty();
        }
    }

    private final String property;

    public Main_PropertyTest(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public void printProperty() {
        System.out.println("And the property is: '" + property + "'.");
    }
}
```

And my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer primaryPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") + ".main.properties"));
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer secondaryPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(System.getProperty("spring.profiles.sub") + ".main.properties"));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setOrder(-1);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Main_PropertyTest main_PropertyTest(@Value("${main.property}") String property) {
        Main_PropertyTest main_PropertyTest = new Main_PropertyTest(property);
        return main_PropertyTest;
    }
}
```

And for completeness, my dev.main.properties and test.main.properties:

```
main.property=dev

main.property=test
```

The main problem is that I get an illegal argument exception. As far as I can tell, what I have written should be the javaconfig equivalent of this method: http://taidevcouk.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/overriding-a-packaged-spring-application-properties-file-via-an-external-file/
Unfortunately I get the following error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'main.property' in string value "${main.property}". Note that I also need to take care of the case where there is no sub-environment, and this is the case I have started with (although I get the same error even if both files exist). If I remove the bean which sets up the second propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer, then it all works fine (by which I mean dev.main.properties is loaded and "And the property is: 'dev'." is printed out).

A secondary problem is that the code doesn't look great, and each layer of the system will need two PSPC's set-up so that they can access these properties. Furthermore, it requires a lot of manual calls to System.getProperty(), since I couldn't pass ${spring.profiles.active} to PSPC.setLocation();

**Note:** I have tried @PropertySources({primaryproperties, secondaryProperties}), but this fails because secondaryProperties does not exist. I have also tried @Autowired Environment environment; and getting the properties from that, but the secondary PSPC causes the environment to not be autowired...

So following this lengthy explanation, my questions are:

- Is this the right way of solving this problem?
- If so, what is wrong with my configuration?
- How can I simplify the configuration (if at all)?
- Is there an alternative mechanism available which would solve my problem?

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: For starters your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` annotated bean methods should be static methods. Next why use 2 `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` whereas you can simply use 1? And next to that I strongly suggest to simply use the `@PropertySource` annotation for loading your files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Out of interest, why should they be static? Now that you mention it I notice all the examples I've been using are static... I think I need to use 2 PSPC's, because one of the sources may not exist and if I only have one, then it tells me the file doesn't exist on start-up, however I may be misunderstanding the ability of PSPC, or missing some feature which can achieve this? I did try @PropertySource, but had the same problem as with a single PSPC. If the file doesn't exist then I get an error, there doesn't seem to be a way of ignoring failure on a missing file.

Comment: They need to be static because they need to be available before anything else, this is kind of a lifecycle thing. You can still use a @PropertySource for the initial file (judging from the configuration that is always there). Then inject the Environment and add a PropertySource yourself (if the file exists).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I'll try injecting the environment and adding a property source, that sounds like the solution. :)

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your configuration is flawed when configuring `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` with java config the methods should be static. However it can be even easier, instead of registering your own `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` utilize the default `@PropertySource` support.

Rewerite your jav config to the following

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name="main", value= "${spring.profiles.active}.main.properties")
public class PropertyTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        String resource = env.getProperty("spring.profiles.sub") +".main.properties";
        Resource props = new ClassPathResource(resource);
        if (env instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment && props.exists()) {
            MutablePropertySources sources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();
            sources.addBefore("main", new ResourcePropertySource(props)); 
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Main_PropertyTest main_PropertyTest(@Value("${main.property}") String property) {
        Main_PropertyTest main_PropertyTest = new Main_PropertyTest(property);
        return main_PropertyTest;
    }
}
```

This should first load the `dev.main.properties` and additionally the `test.main.properties` which will override the earlier loaded properties (when filled ofcourse).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to use static beans but this didn't solve my problem. Just saw your comment, so I'll try that. :)

Comment: I'v update my answer to reflect the earlier comment. You could also check this way if the `spring.profiles.sub` property has been set by first calling `containsProperty` on the `Environment`. That way it makes it completly optional to set that property.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! That's a lot neater, and I'm happy now. :)

Comment: By using the environment you could also simply use the environment variables instead of setting them to other system variables. Although due to the fact that you are setting the `spring.profiles.active` variable you probably need this. An additional comment instead of doing it inside a `@PostConstruct` method you could move it to an `ApplicationContextInitializer` instead. (especially useful when you are using a web application).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with overwriting already existing properties in integration tests

I came up with this solution:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
    SomeProdConfig.class,
    MyWebTest.TestConfig.class
})
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyWebTest {


    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Inject
        private Environment env;


        @PostConstruct
        public void overwriteProperties() throws Exception {
            final Map<String,Object> systemProperties = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env)
                .getSystemProperties();
            systemProperties.put("some.prop", "test.value");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With some of the kinds of problems you are describing, I've used `ReflectionTestUtils` with great success.

Here's a [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78206625/501113) addressing how I accomplished it.

tl;dr

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.vendorApi, "apiKey", VENDOR_API_BAD_API_KEY)
```