# override spring annoted value with environment variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, environment-variables

I want to override spring config value with environment variable which is taken from properties file .

```
java -jar -Xdebug -Dmy_url=www.google.com Management-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

> @Value("${site.base}")
>
> private String siteBase;

I want to override the value **${site.base}** with  environment variable with **my_url** which is taken from properties file.

Comment: Are you looking for this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212558/how-do-i-configure-spring-to-partially-and-optionally-override-properties#answer-20213990

Comment: Try this `java -jar -Xdebug Management-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --my_url=www.google.com`