# How to override properties by each test in unitTest

Tags: java, junit, spring-test

I have the next configuration in my unit Test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:itest.properties", properties = "server.username = inlined")

public class IqClientImplTest
```

With this configuration on my test class, I'm changing the `server.username` property from the one defined in the .properties file to `inlined` But I need to do this at the test level, because I need to override this property value with different values by each test, for example in one could be empty and in another one I need the admin value.

Do you know how can I override the .properties value at the test level and not at the class level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject Environment class inside your test class. Then you can try customize environment properties.

eg:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35769953/1811348

Here you will not change anything in postconstruct, but in your own test method where you want to override settings.

and to reset you can add DirtiesContext annotation to the test method.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

Other way is to set system property in each test method with:

```
System.setProperty("simple_test_env_property","somevalue");
```

also ensure you add dirtiescontext. Maybe dirtiescontext is overkill and not required but you can checkout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple pattern that I use based on the [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) class as of Spring Boot 2.5.

The key thing to remember is to ensure the test restores whatever it is being mutated to the same state it was before the mutation prior to ending the test. Otherwise, this can become the source of bugs that are very difficult to track down.

```java
  private static final String VENDOR_API_BAD_API_KEY = "ThIsIsNtAvAlIdApIkEy";

  @Test
  public void testVerifyPathwayBadApiKey() {
    //capture original value (injected as a property somewhere prior to this test context)
    //  to be restored to avoid impacting tests that follow
    var apiKeyValueOriginal = (String) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(this.vendorApi, "apiKey");
    try {
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.vendorApi, "apiKey", VENDOR_API_BAD_API_KEY);

      //Code depending on the changed value in this.vendorApi

    }
    finally {
      //reset to original value
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.vendorApi, "apiKey", apiKeyValueOriginal);
    }
  }
}
```